# check if domain name contains certain words

Tags: php

I am trying to check if domain name contain blacklisted words.Below is my code so far

```
function teststringforbadwords($string,$banned_words) {
    foreach($banned_words as $banned_word) {
        if(stristr($string,$banned_word)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


$banned_words= array("casino","payday","prescription");


if (teststringforbadwords("casino123.com",$banned_words)) {
echo "banned word found";
continue;
}
```

Above code works for `casino.com` but not `casino123.com` , Any help will be appreciated.

Note : this is not duplicate The question mentioned just check for 1 word , I am checking array of words here.

Comment: who marked this as duplicate ? The question mentioned just check for 1 word , I am checking array of words here

Comment: There is no mark for duplicate here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php check if string contains a value in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445798/php-check-if-string-contains-a-value-in-array)

Comment: copied answer from the above possible dup post, `stripos(json_encode($array),'mystring') !== false`, and my opinion answer, `str_ireplace($banned_words, "", $str) !== $str`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition is pretty much the opposite,  should be:

```
foreach($banned_words as $banned_word) {
    if(stristr($string,$banned_word) !== false){
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is backwards. You want to return true if the banned word is found, right?

```
if(stristr($string,$banned_word)){
return true;
}
```

...because, when you call the function you say:

```
if(teststringforbadwords("casino123.com",$banned_words)){
echo "banned word found";
}
```