# Conditions in PHP for string(s) that contain specific words

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing, contains

Here are the `9` different Strings that I want to apply if else conditions(`or something better`) for:

```
1. Automated - Under the Hood: iPhone 6 running iOS 9
2. Automated - AU/NZ:  iPhone 6 running iOS 9
3. Automated - DRM: iPhone 6 running iOS 9 
4. Automated - Ads regression: iPhone6 running iOS 9
5. Automated - Ads regression: iPhone 5 running iOS 8 
6. Automated - UI & Functional Regression on iPad 2 running iOS 8
7. Automated - Under the Hood: iPad Air on iOS 8
8. Automated - AU/NZ: iPad Air running iOS 8
9. Automated - DRM iPadAir running iOS 8
```

Every time, I will get one of `above string` and that will be assigned to a `PHP variable`. `It is possible that the order of words or position of few words in any string can change`. But certain things like `OS, phone type, OS version and test type will not change`. Based on what specific words, a string contains, I will do a REST api call.

For example, if PHP var is holding the 1st string i.e if

`$test = Automated - Under the Hood: iPhone 6 running iOS 9`, then I will make #1 rest api call.

So, the way I think I should do is this:

```
if ($test/string contains "under", "hood", "iPhone 6", "iOS 9") then do #1rest call (that i have command for)

else if ($test/string contains "AU", "NZ", "iPhone 6", "iOS 9") then do #2rest call..
....
else
... for all the above 9 strings.
```

So far I have tried .contains() in PHP. `Will a switch be a better alternative to this? If yes, an example would be good to have.` Otherwise, better way to do in if-else conditions / regex.

Comment: make all string to array check with in_array function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445798/php-check-if-string-contains-a-value-in-array

Comment: What is `contains()` in PHP?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub : all done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a named capturing group with the following regex:

```
-\s*(?<what>.*):.*?(?<device>ip(?:hone|ad(?: ?air)?))\s*(?<model>\d)?.*ios\s*(?<os>\d)
```

You can try it there at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cC4sA2/1)

If you want to run [PHP](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0ce790f973965d689a1412f1512be85c422f3f45):

```
$re = "/-\s*(?<what>.*):.*?(?<device>ip(?:hone|ad(?: ?air)?))\s*(?<model>\d)?.*ios\s*(?<os>\d)/mi"; 
$strs = array(
    "1. Automated - Under the Hood: iPhone 6 running iOS 9",
    "2. Automated - AU/NZ:  iPhone 6 running iOS 9",
    "3. Automated - DRM: iPhone 6 running iOS 9 ",
    "4. Automated - Ads regression: iPhone6 running iOS 9",
    "5. Automated - Ads regression: iPhone 5 running iOS 8 ",
    "6. Automated - UI & Functional Regression: on iPad 2 running iOS 8",
    "7. Automated - Under the Hood: iPad Air on iOS 8",
    "8. Automated - AU/NZ: iPad Air running iOS 8",
    "9. Automated - DRM: iPadAir running iOS 8"
); 

foreach($strs as $str)
{
    preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
    echo "What: " . $matches['what'][0] . "\n";
    echo "Device: " . $matches['device'][0] . "\n";
    echo "Device version: " . $matches['model'][0] . "\n";
    echo "Os: " . $matches['os'][0] . "\n";   
}
```

---

Then you can use `matches['nameOfGroup'][0]` within an `if` condition (with method `in_array` for example) to execute the code you want to run.

Choosing between a `switch` or a big if/else condition will depend of you code and the method you want to execute depending of the results.