# How to start searching a string from a question mark exists in the string "?" and backward?

Tags: php, arrays, regex

For example I have this :

```
$string = 'PHP is a server side web programming language , Do you like PHP ?  , PHP is fantastic';

$array = array('html','css','javascript','ajax','html5','css3','jquery','PHP');

foreach($array as $ar){
   //Check if one of the $array values exists before the question mark '?' in the $string
}
```

I want to search before the question mark "?" in the $string only , so if the $array value "PHP" is not straight before the question mark "?" then nothing would happen as it's not exist , The PHP could be any of the other values in the $array so I don't know the length the value should be found at , I mean the word could be repeated and with different length.

i.e : `$string = 'html .... , html is fantastic , Do you like html? , I love html';` , now the length of the word is bigger , and it could be bigger than that.

How to find the only straight "PHP" before the question mark and after "like" ['Do you like PHP ?'] what ever the length of the word is ?

Comment: Not to be picky, but there's also a space before the question mark.

Comment: What happened with your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46937148/how-to-search-the-end-of-a-string-for-a-text-exists-in-an-array)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search the end of a string for a text exists in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46937148/how-to-search-the-end-of-a-string-for-a-text-exists-in-an-array)

Comment: @ishegg: Great, haven't noticed.

Comment: @Jan , It's not duplicated , the two questions are totally different , the first is resolved but this is not .

Comment: @ishegg , maybe it's similar because of the way I explained it with , but the two questions are different

Comment: @Joe, if it's resolved, **accept the answer** that helped you the most.

Comment: How about joining the array items into a single alternation regex. `$rgx = '(' . join('|',$array) . ')\s*\?';` then do a find all type of regex search, which will create an array of things found in the string. The advantage is that it only requires a single regex and a single pass. You'll have to pre-regex\_escape all the items in the array first.

Answer (score 0):

You could do what you want with regular expressions, but if you tokenize the text you'll have more flexibility:

```
<?php
$string = 'PHP is a server side web programming language , Do you like PHP?, Do you like Javascript ? What is Ajax?? Coding is fun.';
$find = ['html','css','javascript','ajax','html5','css3','jquery','php'];

// Convert to lowercase and add whitespace to punctuation
$tokenized_string = preg_replace("/([^a-zA-Z0-9'-_ ])/", ' \1 ', strtolower($string));

// Condense multiple sequential spaces into a single space
$tokenized_string = preg_replace('/ {2,}/', ' ', $tokenized_string);

// Tokenize the text into words
$words = explode(' ', $tokenized_string);

// Find search terms directly preceding a question mark token
$question_words = array_filter(
    array_intersect($words, $find),
    function($k) use ($words) {
        return @$words[$k+1] == '?';
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);

// Output our matches
var_dump($question_words);
```

This creates a normalized array of tokens as `$words`, like:

```
array(30) {
  [0] =>
  string(3) "php"
  [1] =>
  string(2) "is"
  [2] =>
  string(1) "a"
  [3] =>
  string(6) "server"
  [4] =>
  string(4) "side"
  [5] =>
  string(3) "web"
  [6] =>
  string(11) "programming"
  [7] =>
  string(8) "language"
  [8] =>
  string(1) ","
  [9] =>
  string(2) "do"
  [10] =>
  string(3) "you"
  [11] =>
  string(4) "like"
  [12] =>
  string(3) "php"
  [13] =>
  string(1) "?"
  [14] =>
  string(1) ","
  [15] =>
  string(2) "do"
  [16] =>
  string(3) "you"
  [17] =>
  string(4) "like"
  [18] =>
  string(10) "javascript"
  [19] =>
  string(1) "?"
  [20] =>
  string(4) "what"
  [21] =>
  string(2) "is"
  [22] =>
  string(4) "ajax"
  [23] =>
  string(1) "?"
  [24] =>
  string(1) "?"
  [25] =>
  string(6) "coding"
  [26] =>
  string(2) "is"
  [27] =>
  string(3) "fun"
  [28] =>
  string(1) "."
  [29] =>
  string(0) ""
}
```

It returns an array of search terms found before a question mark, keyed by their position in the `$words` array:

```
array(3) {
  [12] =>
  string(3) "php"
  [18] =>
  string(10) "javascript"
  [22] =>
  string(4) "ajax"
}
```

This makes the assumption that you're not using search terms like `node.js`, which contain punctuation within them, although you could accommodate that fairly easily with this approach.

It also assumes you don't have any multiple word search terms like `amazon s3`.  Instead of doing the `array_intersect()` you could iterate through question mark tokens with `array_keys($words, '?')` and check for your search terms in the tokens preceding it based on their word length.